# Storing a function call in a Django model

Tags: python, django, dictionary, django-models

Currently I am storing a series of objects as a dictionary of dictionaries, and within this I store calls to functions defined outside of the dictionary. These functions are specific to the objects, and cannot be generalised. In the dictionary I can refer to the function directly eg: `'some_property': function_name`, and when I call that later on `dictionary['some_property'](arg_1, arg_2)`and the function gets called. I am looking migrate this dictionary of dictionaries to a django model, but I cannot see how I can replicate this functionality from a model.

What I currently have:

```
dictionaries.py

def year_camel_month(filename, **kwargs):
    month = kwargs['month'].title()
    return filename.format(str(kwargs['year']), month)


def year_month(filename, **kwargs):
    month = kwargs['month']
    return filename.format(str(kwargs['year']), month.lower())


data_source_families = {
    'dataset_1': {
        'source_url': 'https://example.org/url/subfolder',
        'slug': 'slug_that_changes_predictably_over_time{}-{}',
        'slug_treatment': year_camel_month
    },
    'dataset_2': {
        'source_url': 'https://example2.org/url/subfolder',
        'slug': 'slug_that_changes_predictably_over_time{}-{}',
        'slug_treatment': year_month
        },
}
```

Which then gets called when combined with a user-defined time frame later on:

```
get_data.py

from .dictionaries import data_source_families

slug = data_source_families[selected_dataset]['slug']
processed_slug = data_source_families[selected_dataset]['slug_treatment'](slug, some_kwargs)
url = data_source_families[selected_dataset]['source_url'] + processed_slug
```

And this is working fine. I am looking to develop functionality to improve consistency (and make these data available to another programme) by creating a django model that replicates this, something like this:

```
models.py

def year_camel_month(filename, **kwargs):
    month = kwargs['month'].title()
    return filename.format(str(kwargs['year']), month)


def year_month(filename, **kwargs):
    month = kwargs['month']
    return filename.format(str(kwargs['year']), month.lower())


class DataSourceFamilies(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    source_url = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=False)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False)
--> slug_treatment = models._____(choices=list_of_functions)    <--

    def __str___(self):
        return self.name.name
```

Does something like this exist? How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Sry but your question is a little bit confusing to me... why you not work with class methods? you can declare all functions at your call and call it whereever you want,  if each slug_treatment have multiples functions that you programmer or end-user will choice, pass it as parameter.

Comment: Or if you want to show results in table as column based in some algorithm that user choice in slug_treatment, you could use property method that check column slug_treatment and run which function you want based on chosen value from it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot store functions (Python functions I mean) in a SQL database, indeed. But you can store any text value, and you can have a dict of 'key:func' in your model, ie:

```
class DataSourceFamilies(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    source_url = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=False)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False)

    SLUG_TREATEMENTS = [
        # key, label, function
        ('year_camel_month', "Year, Camel month", year_camel_month),
        ('year_month': "Year month", year_month),
    ]  
    SLUG_TREATEMENTS_ACTIONS = {
        k: func 
        for k, label, func in SLUG_TREATEMENTS
    }

    SLUG_TREATEMENTS_CHOICES = [
        (k, label)
        for k, label, func in SLUG_TREATEMENTS
    ]

    slug_treatment = models.CharField(
        max_length=50 # let's have a little headroom, 
        choices=SLUG_TREATMENT_CHOICES
        )

    def get_slug_treatment_func(self):
        return self.SLUG_TREATEMENTS_ACTIONS[self.slug_treatment]
```

Comment: Thanks, I have implemented this, will test on Monday. One think I did need to do to get this to work was to have the value first, then name in the tuples within the lists to not get Django errors where it was trying to unpack an unexpected number of items.

Comment: I have tried this but I am getting errors - if I have the key, value pair the way round you have in your example the choices appear as blanks in the admin page. If I select one of the 'blanks' it saves the string of the name as part of the model. If i revers to have a value, key pair, I get the correct name in the admin page, when I try to save it errors and says that the selections are not valid. Any suggestions? @bruno-desthuilliers

Comment: yes sorry wrote this a bit too quickly, will update this code example.

Comment: This seems to have done the trick - thanks. I chose this answer over the alternative provided by @ritlew as it would lead to less duplication.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you could do is to use a CharField and then [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval) it. However, using `eval` is usually a huge security risk. Any python code that enters it will be executed, and you do not want anything like that in a web application.

Another option is to have a lookup system. You could, say, have a CharField with choices that corresponds to a dictionary like so:

```
models.py
...
slug_treatment = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=function_choices)
...
```

And then:

```
get_data.py

function_lookup = {
    "year_month": year_month,
    "year_camel_month": year_camel_month
}

processed_slug = function_lookup[data_source.slug_treatment](slug, some_kwargs)
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. It does seem to work, but I have 50+ functions to choose from in my implementation. The fact that I would have to have a list of choices in the model, then a dictionary to perform the lookup would mean that I would have more duplication than the answer submitted by @bruno-desthuilliers. I do really appreciate the advice though!

Answer (score 0):

Sry its a bit confusing to me, but based on what i understood, maybe you can declare all function in your class and use slug_treament as parameter to which function will be called when you need.

Lets draw it a bit

```
YEAR_CAMEL_MONTH=1 
YEAR_MONTH=2
SLUG_TREATEMENTS_CHOICES = [
        (YEAR_CAMEL_MONTH: 'year_camel_month'),
        (YEAR_MONTH: 'year_month'),
    ]

class DataSourceFamilies(models.Model):
    ...
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False)
    slug_treatment = models.IntegerField(choices=SLUG_TREATMENT_CHOICES)

    def year_camel_month(self):
        ... # Your logic
        return formated_slug

    def year_month(self):
        ... # Your logic
        return formated_slug

    def save(self *args **kwargs):
        if self.slug_treatment == YEAR_CAMEL_MONTH:
            self.slug = self.year_camel_month()
        elif self.slug_treatment == YEAR_MONTH:
            self.slug = self.year_month()
        super(DataSourceFamilies, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Or you can use it as prorperty method instead of persisted data (so the slug will be evaluated everytime your call your queryset, so its is dinamic instead of persisted" *Obs.: Property methods works like columns from your database, but its not persisted, its like CAST in database*

```
class DataSourceFamilies(models.Model):
    ...        
    slug_treatment = models.IntegerField(choices=SLUG_TREATMENT_CHOICES)

    @property
    def slug(self):
        if self.slug_treatment == YEAR_CAMEL_MONTH:
            return slug = self.year_camel_month()
        elif self.slug_treatment == YEAR_MONTH:
            return slug = self.year_month()
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/models/

*Obs.: If you trying to get code from text and evaluate it in python i guess its possible, but **is highly unsafe, and i do not recommend it***

Comment: Maybe... just maybe... you can generic call the function passing as arguments to you properpy or save method... instead of trying evaluate the entire function body

Comment: Keep in mind that any programmer can edit your "Admin Form" or anything that you will use to user interact and change the entire code, since its code so text you will not be able to compleate valided it... so peoples can just write some harmful code and when you runs it at your backend you even damage your server...